# how you can render a video in fullscreen when rotating the device

Tags: ionic-framework, fullscreen, screen-orientation

I'm trying to render a video in fullscreen when rotating the device on my Ionic application. I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) to catch the device rotation, and the FullScreen API.

```
window.screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", function () { 
  if (window.screen.orientation.type.startsWith("landscape") && !document.fullscreenElement) { 
    try { container.requestFullscreen(); 
    } catch (err) {...); } 
  } else if ( window.screen.orientation.type.startsWith("portrait") && document.fullscreenElement ) 
    { try { document.exitFullscreen(); } catch (err) { ... } } }); });
```

This works fine if I touch the video before rotating the device, but if I don't touch it I get this error

> Msg: Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only
> be initiated by a user gesture.

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) this should work.
I've also tried with "window.addEventListener("orientationchange",..." but it doesn't look to change. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't make a video play full screen unless the user actually taps the "view in full screen" button.

You can use a video play like [VideoJS](https://videojs.com/) and add CSS styles to the player to make it *appear* like the video is in "full-screen" mode when the device is rotated, but it is actually only covering the HTML document.

A starting point for the css would be:

```
#video-js-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This exact solution unfortunately doesn't work for me, but thanks anyway I'll try to "fake" a fullscreen like you suggeste.